# NodeJs + OracleDB + load sql file

Tags: node.js, oracle, file

The problem is simple, I cant load an sql file using the oracledb connector. It seems it doesn´t supoport more than one sentence.

Any idea how to load an sql file?

```
var oracledb = require('oracledb');
var fs = require('fs');

fs.readFile("test.sql", function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    }

    connect(data.toString());
});

function connect(sql) {
    oracledb.getConnection({
            user: "****",
            password: "***",
            connectString: "****"
        },
        function(err, connection) {
            if (err) {
                console.error(err.message);
                return;
            }
            connection.execute(
                sql, [],
                function(err, result) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.error(err.message);
                        doRelease(connection);
                        return;
                    }
                    console.log(result.metaData);
                    console.log(result.rows);
                    doRelease(connection);
                });
        });
}

function doRelease(connection) {
    connection.release(
        function(err) {
            if (err) {
                console.error(err.message);
            }
        });
}
```

It throws an error:

ORA-00911: invalid character

The sql is here:

```
select * from DEFECTO;
select * from ESQUEMA;
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, I found a workaround for multiple sql statements, and is just using exec:

```
exec('echo exit | sqlplus -S ****/***@//****:1521/**** @sqlfile.sql', ["bash"],
                function(error, stdout, stderr) {
                    callback();
                }
            );
```

Answer (score 1):

Battled with this for a long time before realizing it's the semicolon that the connection.execute() method doesn't like. So long as your SQL statement doesn't conclude with one, reading from a file works.

Answer (score 0):

As you discovered, node-oracledb's connection.execute() method only executes one statement.  This is the same as other languages. Instead of putting your SQL statements in a SQL*Plus file, try putting them in a .js file as an array of strings.  Then process each element of the array.  This will give you better control over transactions and error handling.

Comment: Well ... imagine a database dump .... it will not be something practical to convert it to a js file

Comment: For Oracle->Oracle dumps, use a better format than SQL .e.g export with Data Pump. For 3rd party imports into Oracle, the structure of any data might be consistent so you can parse it using JS and use node-oracledb to insert the data.  Bottom line: use what works.